# How to download a file when I have the raw file data in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have been battling with this one issue for about two days now and don't have any solution. I get data back from an API on our old system with regards to Attachments and other data. Now if I run the query in postman, I get the actual document showing up. Now in VS Code, I do the call on the backend in Nodejs and send that data to my frontend, which when I log it to the console gives me the raw data of the file:

```
%PDF-1.6
```

%����
199 0 obj <</Linearized 1/L 891424/O 201/E 139951/N 6/T 887396/H [ 1236 433]>>
endobj

xref
199 47
0000000016 00000 n
0000001669 00000 n
0000001936 00000 n
0000002504 00000 n
0000002546 00000 n
0000002684 00000 n
0000002821 00000 n
0000002959 00000 n
0000003072 00000 n
0000004421 00000 n
0000005810 00000 n
0000006352 00000 n
0000006822 00000 n
0000006961 00000 n
0000007241 00000 n
0000007503 00000 n
0000007529 00000 n
0000008087 00000 n
0000010099 00000 n
0000010543 00000 n
0000010810 00000 n
0000012804 00000 n
0000014560 00000 n
0000016676 00000 n
0000019142 00000 n
0000021085 00000 n
0000030182 00000 n
0000041511 00000 n
0000050173 00000 n
0000059390 00000 n
0000059493 00000 n
0000059770 00000 n
0000059839 00000 n
0000060279 00000 n
0000119811 00000 n
0000121391 00000 n
0000123466 00000 n
0000126935 00000 n
0000129729 00000 n
0000131785 00000 n
0000133109 00000 n
0000135857 00000 n
0000138698 00000 n
0000139745 00000 n
0000139808 00000 n
0000139882 00000 n
0000001236 00000 n
trailer
<</Size 246/Prev 887384/Root 200 0 R/Info 198 0 R/ID[<8D8F16B67F948647AA1C78C6338DE7E5><623F133706D1C94384C1BFBFEFB70137>]>>
startxref
0
%%EOF

245 0 obj<</Length 351/Filter/FlateDecode/I 420/S 260>>stream
x�b`b`����� �bÁ+P���#�8���^�y���3��RZ��_[6�Z��Q�֋m��=wX�˖�

What I need help with is in my callback function....how do I get this data in a format where I can just immediately download it with the correct file structure showing. I have really tried quite a few options and nothing seems to work.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a file in memory for user to download, but not through server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server)

Answer (score 0):

Use js-file-download library:

```
import fileDownload from 'js-file-download';

fileDownload(downloadData, fineName);
```

Comment: Hi @davood Sandoghsaz, this works as the other methods I've tried, where it does download the file, but the PDF is blank. Should I do something with the data beforehand to make it work correctly?

Comment: Hi @Niishaw, Do you get data from API?

Comment: yes on the backend, I do the same call I do in Postman and that brings back the pdf data which I then return to the front-end. I can see the data when I log it to console, but like I said, downloading it, returns a blank PDF file and I'm not sure if I should alter the returned data? As of right now, I only store it in a variable

Comment: How do you call API? Do you use of Axios?

Comment: You must send a config with call API `{ responseType: 'blob' }`

Comment: [code]async getAttachments(params) {
    const id = params.actionId;
    try {
      const resultsData = await axios.post(
        "URL",
        {
          function: "get_attachment",
          attachment_id: id,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );

     
      return { d: resultsData.data };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return false;
    }
  }[code]

Comment: As I said add `responseType` config to your header's request and check it again

Comment: And download the file when the variable of your data is not null: `useEffect(() => { if (downloadData) fileDownload(downloadData, fineName); }, [downloadData]);`